# Multi Json objects - Run through code - Python

Tags: python, json, object

What I was planning to do is to have a multiple JSON objects, for example:

```
{
    "Profiles": {
        "profile_0": {
            "Name": "Hellow",
            "Age": "8",
            "Email": "Stackoverflow@gmail.com"
        },
        "profile_1": {
            "Name": "Bell",
            "Age": "12",
            "Email": "Stackoverflow123@gmail.com"
        }
        #Profile_2 etc etc
    }
}
```

and my plan is to make the json profile/objects to work concurrently through my code.

1. Use the profiles, between 0 - x
2. concurrently it with my code
3. When finished - exit

A more visual representation:

[image: My Thought]

*The issues I have now:*

I can read one JSON object at this moment with this code:

```
with open('profileMulti.json', 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as json_data:
    config = json.load(json_data)

    get_profile = lambda key: [config['Profiles']['profile_%i' % i][key] for i in range(0, len(config['Profiles'].keys()))]
```

Which gives me this output.

```
print(get_profile('Name'))
# ["Hellow", "Bell"]

print(get_profile('Age'))
# ["8", "12"]
```

An example for code that can be made out of this

```
 "email": config["Email"],
 "PersonNumber": config["PersonNumber"],
 "postal_code": config["ZipCode"],
 "given_name": config["Name"],
 "Last_name": config["LastName"]
```

^ This is from my code on below.

*What I expect to happened* is that inside the code where we have those information such as Name, Lastname, email and all that. To take from Json profiles the information, Load it into the code, Do the rest and then exit. All that should work concurrently which means

When I run the program, It looks how many profiles there is and then exceute it in my code concurrently and then when all finish then quit. So that mean that profile1 should not mix exemple with profile2. All are for their each and should be the same way threated like the other.

**CODE**

```
    with open('profileMulti.json', 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as json_data:
    config = json.load(json_data)

NameUrl = config["Url"]

myNote = config["My-Note"]

def checkoutNames(NameUrl, nameID):

#Request & other codes - Removed to recude the code
#......
#......
    headers = {
        'Referer': '',
        'Content-Type': ''
    }
    payload = {
        "shared": {
            "challenge": {
                "email": config["Email"],
                "PersonNumber": config["PersonNumber"],
                "postal_code": config["ZipCode"],
                  "given_name": config["Name"],
                "Last_name": config["LastName"],

                "street_address": config["Address"],
                "postal_code": config["ZipCode"],
                "city": config["City"],
                "country": config["Country"],
                "email": config["Email"],
                "phone": config["Phone"],
            }

def checkoutNotes(NamesUrl, NamesPost):

#Request & other codes - Removed to recude the code
#......
#......

    headers = {
        'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, /; q=0.01',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        'Referer': NameUrl,
        'Connection': 'keep-alive'
    }
    payloadInfo = {
        "Information": {
            "Color": config["Color"],
            "house_number": config["houseNumber"],
            "year": config["Year"]
      }
    }    
def wipe():
    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')

def main():
    time.sleep(1)

    FindName(myNote)

if _name_ == '_main_':
    try: {
        main()
    }
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        wipe()
```

basically n ow you can see in def checkInfo() there is payload and also in CheckoutNotes there is payloadInfo... Those is the one that I want to input from multiple Json files and like quamrana said. to make all that concurrently.

So basically in the beginning I have nameUrl and myNote that needs to get the information from the Json objects one for each concurrently... Then down below there is the funciton `CheckoutNames` Shared that is challenge and there is also some few objects that takes the information from Json profiles and then more below there is another function `checkoutNotes` that also have a different read from json so basically I want it all to run concurrently and for each multiprocess so should every profile have their own thread and to exceute the program for their each profiles that is enter in the Json file concurrently.

Comment: In each of your examples you have `Name = config["Name"]`. How is your code supposed to know which profile it should return?

Comment: @quamrana Good question. That is the problem im also having not knowing how it will know the profiles. I believe it might be my issue there.

Comment: In your visual representation the program branches three ways. Do you mean that the profiles should run concurrently?

Comment: I don't think OP knows what he wants himself, his edit makes no sense with all these additional functions and lots of typos/errors

Comment: Well the thing is I don't wanna leak all my code since it is really big and I don't want to like enter all the code just to make a free pass basically. but @quamrana is on the right way. I want it to run concurrently. I will make a new edit on the code after my dentist appointment with my code that I have created myself and I think that would be easier to understand by then.

Comment: Also I forgot to add the rest of the Json which I don't know if thats matter or not. I can add the whole thing but I think in the codeyou can pretty much what is needed from a  Json file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get every item one by one, just do not flatten the list use a loop instead.

```
import json

with open('profileMulti.json', 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as json_data:
    config = json.load(json_data)

data = config["Profiles"]
for i in data:
    name = data[i]["Name"]
    print(name)
    age = data[i]["Age"]
    print(age)
    email = data[i]["Email"]
    print(email)
```

This will print out like this:

```
Hellow
8
Stackoverflow@gmail.com
Bell
12
Stackoverflow123@gmail.com
```

Comment: I have updated my thread and showed and exempel of my code how it looks ish.. I think it might give you another view of it!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you just want to print it, here is one way to do it.

```
def get_individual_profile(json_data):
    with open('profileMulti.json', 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as json_data:
        config = json.load(json_data)
        top_layer = config.get('Profiles')
        if top_layer:
            top_level_keys = ['profile_{}'.format(i) for i in range(len(top_layer))
            for key in top_level_keys:
                next_layer = top_layer.get(key)
                print 'Info for {}'.format(' '.join(key.capitalize().split('_')))
                print 'Age ---> {}'.format(next_layer.get('Age'))
                print 'Email ---> {}'.format(next_layer.get('Email'))
                print 'Name ---> {}\n'.format(next_layer.get('Name'))
        else:
            print 'No top layer found'
```

Which will print:

```
Info for Profile 0
Age ---> 8
Email ---> Stackoverflow@gmail.com
Name ---> Hellow

Info for Profile 1
Age ---> 12
Email ---> Stackoverflow123@gmail.com
Name ---> Bell
```

Comment: I have updated my thread and showed and exempel of my code how it looks ish.. I think it might give you another view of it!

Also im checking out hte code now aswell. But I think if you see the new edit you might get the right vision of it!

Comment: the right version? your code that you just posted makes absolutely no sense. there is an error in your very first line, you have a bunch of functions which I do not understand why they are there. you asked for a certain output and this delivers that exact output. if you want to make it into a script with a `main` function, then that is on you to take this segment of code and adapt it into that.

Comment: Alright hold on. I will try make it right now. Give me a minute or two!

Comment: @aws_apprentice: Can you convert your answer to create a list containing every `next_layer` and pass each of these to a thread/process which converts them to strings and finally joins the threads and prints all the strings?

Comment: I would really appreciate it! I think @quamrana is on the right spot understanding me but I will make it up in around 2 hours. I will add my script that Im using those functions.

Comment: @quamrana what is the point of passing these to a multiprocessing module? this is not exactly a computationally heavy task. also this is not a code writing service, OP has been unclear, provided two different examples of code, given the output he has provided I have provided an answer for that. if he shows an example of a different output, i.e a list which holds all these variables then I will gladly change my code

Comment: @aws_apprentice: Ok, lets see what happens when the OP get back to this. You've almost convinced me to vote to close.

Comment: Alright! There we go. I just updated the post and I hope it is more clear now when its from my script I have made. There is alot more but not important stuff but I think everything that I have in the script should be fine

Comment: I hope the code is alot better and more understable. Basically now as you can see there is some config["xxx"] which is from my json. So far I have only made one Json object which works fine. But now I want to upgrade it by having those thoughts as you said before like with concurrently and so on. So I hope you understand and please. If there is more confusion please just write back!

Answer (score 1):

This code shows how you get the same results either processing profiles one at a time, or concurrently using `multiprocessing`:

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
import json

profiles_string = '''
{
    "Profiles": {
        "profile_0": {
            "Name": "Hellow",
            "Age": "8",
            "Email": "Stackoverflow@gmail.com"
        },
        "profile_1": {
            "Name": "Bell",
            "Age": "12",
            "Email": "Stackoverflow123@gmail.com"
        }
    }
}
'''

def get_individual_profiles(config):
    top_layer = config.get('Profiles')
    if top_layer:
        top_level_keys = ['profile_{}'.format(i) for i in range(len(top_layer))]
        return [(key,top_layer.get(key)) for key in top_level_keys]
    return []

def stringify(key, next_layer):
    return [
        'Info for {}'.format(' '.join(key.capitalize().split('_'))),
        'Age ---> {}'.format(next_layer.get('Age')),
        'Email ---> {}'.format(next_layer.get('Email')),
        'Name ---> {}'.format(next_layer.get('Name'))
        ]

#Note how I've used json.loads to read a string 
config = json.loads(profiles_string)
profiles = get_individual_profiles(config)
print(profiles)

print('one at a time:')
for item in profiles:
    print(stringify(*item))

pool = ThreadPool()

# Launch a process for each item
threads = [pool.apply_async(stringify, tuple(item)) for item in profiles]

# get() the results as each finishes
results = [res.get() for res in threads]
print('threaded results:')
for item in results:
    print(item)
```

Note that a real application would replace `stringify` with the real processing.

Credits to aws_apprentice for `get_individual_profiles` and `stringify`

Comment: Alright! There we go. I just updated the post and I hope it is more clear now when its from my script I have made. There is alot more but not important stuff but I think everything that I have in the script should be fine

Comment: I hope the code is alot better and more understable. Basically now as you can see there is some config["xxx"] which is from my json. So far I have only made one Json object which works fine. But now I want to upgrade it by having those thoughts as you said before like with concurrently and so on. So I hope you understand and please. If there is more confusion please just write back!

Comment: Also I forgot to add the rest of the Json which I don't know if thats matter or not. I can add the whole thing but I think in the codeyou can pretty much what is needed from a  Json file

Comment: I think you need to reduce the code as much as possible. I don't see how any of the http processing is relevant at all.

Comment: Okey will do right away. I was more thinking just so you know what I was planning ish. But I will do it now. I was just scared that I provied to little information.

Comment: I will re-edit my whole main question again. Maybe I will get it more understandble now with MCVE

Comment: Alright there we go. I think I have made it the most clear I could ever possible think. I have re-written the whole text and it should be nice to read now. Please feel free to comment again if anything more :D